# Ruby Mechanize - How to parse the site response before Mechanize parses it?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, mechanize

**Problem:**

When parsing a website there are some characters that make Mechanize do not parse it correctly.

**Solution Proposed**

- Parse out the response from the website to remove those characters
  BEFORE mechanize tries to parse it.
- Or, remove those characters after Mechanize has parsed the web and then make Mechanize re-parse it to get the links, forms, etc...

**Question**

- How can I access the website response BEFORE it is parsed?
- Or, how can I parse it afterwards and then ask Mechanize to reload it?

thanks!

Comment: Not able to understand your second question.

Comment: My idea was to let mechanize download the website and access it using page.body. Then remove there the characters that i need and then ask the page to re-load/re-parser itself so that i have the forms and links accessible again.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the solution:
You can define your own html parser so that it can act like a hook.

```
class MyParser
  def self.parse(thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block)
    thing = thing.gsub(/\x00/,"")
    Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(thing, url, encoding, options, &block)
  end
end
agent.html_parser = MyParser
search_page = agent.get "https://www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use mechanize to grab the html data if you want to handle parsing yourself. Use some other gem to just get the html and then parse it manually. What is the point using mechanize if you are not going to use its parsing ? :|

Comment: Well, i want to use mechanize to parse the html data and give me the list of links, forms, nokogiri output, etc...
But, Mechanize (and Nokogiri) cannot parse the html at all due to those 2 special characters so what i need/want to do is just remove them.